# How can I use the telnet server service, that comes with windows, to listen for a port?

Tags: windows, server, windows-7, telnet

Is there an easy way to use the telnet server from command line?
I can connect with `telnet [ip/domain] [port]` but is there a telnet equivalent of `nc -l -p [port]`?

I've tried using [netcat for windows](https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/) but it didn't support [ANSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences).
I've tried `telnet-server` but that didn't work.

Is there a native Win7 way of making a telnet server? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>The partial answer is `net start telnet`, though there's no easy way to emulate `netcat -e`.</s>

EDIT: Just use netcat, it *can* transmit ansi art, but only telnet can display it.